# First few words of the [stack-overflow] tag wiki are cut off in /tags search results. Makes it seem like you're supposed to use it wrong

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-wiki, tag-search

> [image: 310H55V]

The tag description at `stackoverflow.com/tags` says "TO REFER TO the Stack Overflow website."

> [image: 310H55V]

The REAL tag description says "DO NOT USE!"

This is confusing and should be fixed.

Comment: Most of the tag wiki excerpts seem to miss a few words at the beginning, not just [stack-overflow]

Comment: It seems there is some logic that removes stuff like "use this tag .." and "[tag] is .." from the beginning, having an undesired side effect in this case.

Comment: I prefer this tag just removed. It's just a pain in the rear to keep it clean.

Comment: @Floern My search-foo may be failing me but I've just looked through a dozen pages of questions to see if there's already a bug report or something for the missing first few words in the tag wiki excerpts, and found nothing. Do you know if that's been brought up before?

Comment: @Pnuts Thanks! So with those rules, I guess we should just craft tag excerpts that avoid those rules highlighted in that link and are succinct, that way "Do not use" type messages come through loud and clear.

Comment: Hmmm and we already have a [StackOverflowException] tag, maybe the excerpt should be directing users with an actual StackOverflow error to that tag. Something like "DO NOT USE. If reporting a StackOverflow Exception in your code, use the [StackOverflowException] tag. If your question is about the site StackOverflow.com, post on meta.stackoverflow.com instead. " Obviously people will still ignore the popup as they always do as evidenced by the many DO NOT USE tags used every day, but at least it will be more the fault of the user for not reading and less our fault for a bad tag excerpt.

Comment: @DavyM Stack overflows exist in languages without exceptions.

Comment: Or add "or use the [StackOverflowError] tag," either way, the plain [StackOverflow] tag is just misleading since we have both [StackOverflowException] and [StackOverflowError]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag page gets really tiring when every tag excerpt starts with some bit of fluff ("this tag is for..."). So [it tries to strip those out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82700/new-tags-page-mangles-tag-wiki-excerpts) & get to the meat of the excerpt: *what the tag is actually about*.

Describing what tags *are not for* was never an intended use-case for tag excerpts.

The proper solution here is to re-write the tag excerpt to more quickly get to the important bit of detail: what the tag *is* for. I've gone ahead and done this:

[image: NOT THIS WEBSITE! Use this tag for the error caused by pushing too many items onto the callstack. If you have a question regarding this website, please go to https://meta.stackoverflow.com]

[image: tag page excerpt starts with, "for the error caused by pushing..."]